# What does "Purple label" mean when people are describing a Yamaha YSS-62 soprano sax?

Tags: saxophone

My title pretty much says it all. I recently purchased a Yamaha YSS-62, and I am in heaven. It sounds great and plays easily (I now have a full rack!). But when I do research on the model I repeatedly see references to purple label. Now, this horn does have a label that includes the Yamaha logo and then the word "YAMAHA" on the first line, and then the word "JAPAN" on the second line. The color of this label is what I would describe as dark red. Is this a purple label horn, and how is it different from other YSS-62 soprano saxes?

-------------------- Edit ------------------

When I viewed the label in bright light, it certainly appeared to be purple.

Also, nuggethead suggested that I post a picture of the label, which I am doing now. Unfortunately, the picture is not of great quality, but I took many shots and this was the best one.

-------------------- Edit ------------------

Given the following picture, and the logo and text are definitely purple when viewed in bright light, this must be a YSS-62 Purple label. If someone out there has seen one, and can confirm that Purple label refers to this logo, the word YAMAHA, and the word JAPAN, in purple, I would appreciate the confirmation.

And @Aaron, if you change your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

[image: the bell and logo from a suspected Yamaha YSS-62 purple logo]

Comment: Like @Aaron said, it seems to be a period distinction. A search of “purple logo” gets lots of results including forums and items for sale.

Comment: So, similar slang to the well-known  Conn "naked lady" which refers to a few model types also easily identifed by serial number series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say definitively, but some Google searching suggests that the purple label was used during the earliest period of the 62's construction. It either appears deep red to some people or was changed to a deep red at some point. The purple label period seems to be the one most sought after, and it appears to be what you have.